# Change the default behavior of JMXReporter

Tags: jmx, metrics, gauge, spring-jmx, codahale-metrics

I'm trying to push custom gauge type metrics of my application to JMX using com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter.
It seems like JMXReporter by default pushes the metrics to the endpoint **/metrics** which appends an attribute called **.value** to the metric name i.e. say if my custom metric name is **app.test.count** JMXReporter reports this metric name as **app.test.count.value** (under the endpoint **metrics**).

So, is there a way to make JMXReporter to not to append this **.value** attribute to the metric names? I found [here](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-starter-batch-web/) that for InfluxDBReporter all the gauge type metrics will be appended with **.value**. So, is this the same with JMXReporter? 
If that's the case then **is there any other way how I can report metrics to JMX with the metric name I need**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the ObjectName the metric is published through, but the MBean attribute name is hard-coded into the JmxReporter. JmxReporter$JmxGauge is also private, so, the only way to change it would be to implement your own JmxReporter.